# Should we allow compatibility advice?

Tags: discussion, questions

According to the help page about what's on topic, we don't allow compatibility advice. But sometimes you need that to see which hardware you will buy, and that is on topic. Should we then also mark compatibility advide on-topic?

Here is a recent example I have found: [Can you add higher capacity internal drives than the listed on the official spec sheets?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/can-you-add-higher-capacity-internal-drives-than-the-listed-on-the-official-spec)

Answer (score 2):

Given that compatibility is a prerequisite for a hardware recommendation, I think it's reasonable to allow such questions on this SE.

Such questions may also provide assistance to future hardware recommendation community members and visitors, and may also further improve the quality of questions asked in this SE.